# Conversion from char* buffer to const uint8*

Tags: c++, casting

I have a quite big char* buffer (content of a file, read with streambuf sgetn).
I need to pass it to an internal function, where const uint8* is required.
How can I do this without reinterpret_cast (not allowed)?

Comment: Why would `reinterpret_cast` be forbidden? That makes no sense

Comment: What do you mean by "not allowed"? This is the standard way to cast ptrs in C++. What is the compiler error you got?

Comment: The standard allows you to change the signedness of pointer types with a cast.  You're not violating any strict aliasing rules or anything.

Comment: Not allowed by the project.

Comment: @anaisB -- Then tell us what else is "not allowed".

Comment: That is a weird requirement.  Well, you could set the underlying character type of your stream to unsigned.

Comment: When reinterpret cast is not allowed then memcpy.

Comment: You could try to use `memcpy` and wait until the code reviewer tells you to use `reinterpret_cast` instead.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie only static_cast is allowed

Comment: I was also thinking about memcpy, but it will be a memory waste..

Comment: @paddy, can you please detail " the underlying character type of your stream"? Thanks!

Comment: I mean that if you actually prefer to read the file into a `uint8_t` buffer instead, then you can use `std::basic_fstream<uint8_t>` instead of `std::fstream` (which is an alias of `std::basic_fstream<char>`).  That will provide a streambuf with the desired character type to begin with, so you can have that unsigned type all the way through.  This should work, unless there's some other reason you are forced to store the input buffer as a `char*` in which case you really have no option other than the other suggested techniques which all boil down to a cast at some point.

Comment: @paddy seems that function td::basic_streambuf::sgetn is not parametrized, even if the class it is: streamsize sgetn (char_type* s, streamsize n); So, I had to stay at the premise of char* and decided for the static_cast conversion through void* (which is basically a reinterpret_cast, with other words).

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: Use reinterpret_cast, disobeying the disallowance.

Option 2: Change the premise, and start with an unsigned char (i.e. `std::uint8_t`) buffer instead of `char` buffer, so that there is no need to convert.

Comment: Regarding option 2, I am a bit surprised that pbuf->sgetn (buffer,size); accepted the buffer to be an unsigned char pointer. I know that when working with raw memory this is the representation of char, maybe that's why.

Comment: Sorry, actually did not work. So, if I keep the sgetn function, I have char* as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

With such a restriction, use casting to a desired pointer type through casting to `void*`. Any pointer can be casted to `void*` and it can be casted to any pointer (with keeping or making const if needed).

```
#include <cstdint>

void f(const uint8_t* p) {}

int main() {
  char p[] = "";
  f(static_cast<uint8_t*>(static_cast<void*>(p)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! looks ugly :), but it worked.

Comment: When you're prevented from doing something the right way, the results are often ugly.